# SharePoint Online, share a list with unique permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, share

Is there a way to share a list, just like the users share a site or a document using the "Share" option?  This list has unique permissions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open "LIST" tab on the ribbon
2. "Shared With"
3. "Invite People"

Comment: It should be noted that if the user doesn't have access to the site, there may be issues when they try to access the list that was shared to them.

Comment: @wjervis Theres a note in the dialog: `They'll also get access to the 'Home' site and the sites that share permissions with it.`

Comment: Ah, that's right.  I now remember we only ran into that issue because someone removed them from the site afterwards.

Comment: I am not able to see the "Shared With" option in the calendar. I have full control.

Comment: @Obiliraj change the View to "All Events" or any other List View, then you will have "LIST" tab on the ribbon instead of "CALENDAR"